# MVC UI for ASP.NET CheckboxFor Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I have a big problem with MVC Telerik UI for ASP.NET
I am trying to get a checkbox up for a boolean field. I know we have two input fields to return the value false when the box is not touched.
When I do not touch the CBox, I get the value 'false' as expected. When I check the box, I get false too because the CBOx is returning a string = "true,false" which makes it impossible to convert directly to bool.

View

```
public class role
{
    public string role_name { get; set; }
    public bool add_school { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> test(Models.role role)
    {
        var z = Request["cb_addschool"];
        var x = 1;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

View

```
    @model Models.role

    @using (Html.BeginForm("test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h2>Add a New Role</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.role_name, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.role_name, new { @class = "form-control form-control-big" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(m=>m.add_school).Name("cb_addschool").Label("Add School")
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-login" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Please, any help?

Comment: Remove the `.Name("cb_addschool")` from Kendo code (you should never change the `name` attribute of a control when binding to a model). Then the `add_school` property will be correctly bound in you model when you submit - there is no need for you `var z = Request["cb_addschool"];` line of code

Comment: I saw somewhere in Kendo we should always define the Name attribute?
And the var z was only for testing what the checkbox was really returning

Comment: No. If you remove it and inspect the html your generating, you will see that now its `<input type="checkbox" name="add_school" ... />` which relates to your model property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this code from your action method:

```
var z = Request["cb_addschool"];
```

You have this value inside your **role** model. So this is pointless in this case.

Than remove this attribute from Kendo CheckBoxFor:

```
.Name("cb_addschool")
```

You don't have to need that (the property will be bound correctly without that).

**Small hint:** if you are using Kendo - use the `Kendo().TextBoxFor` method instead of `@Html.TextBoxFor` (or add "`k-textbox`" class to your TextBoxFor - it will use Kendo CSS styles).

Here is an example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.role_name)
.HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Select role", @class = "form-control form-control-big" })
)
```